# MVC with Entity framework 2 objects in same view

Tags: entity-framework, object, model-view-controller, view

im learning MVC with Entity framework. im try to build a view that receive 2 dropdownlist from differents tables. My doubt is should i build a third table to get information or exists a different way to do it?
The objective is create the teams and each team can have multiple elements. how should i do this? based on what i have?
I have like this:
Entities

```
   public class Elemento : IEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Posto")]
        public Posto posto { get; set; }

        public Equipa equipa { get; set; }                
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Primeiro nome")]
        public string Pnome { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Sobrenome")]
        public string Mnome { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Apelido")]
        public string Unome { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display (Name = "Barra/Nº interno")]
        public int Nbarra { get; set; }

        public bool Qhonra { get; set; }

        public bool Qreserva { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Estado { get; set; }
```

```
public class Equipa : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Equipa")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    //public IEnumerable<Elemento> GetElementos {get; set;} 
    public int Estado { get; set; }
}
```

```
Controllers:
```

```
namespace FireHouseGest.web.Controllers
{
    public class ElementosController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IElementoRepository _elementoRepository;
        private readonly IPostoRepository _postoRepository;
        private readonly DataContext _context;

        public ElementosController(IElementoRepository elementoRepository, IPostoRepository postoRepository, DataContext context)
        {
            
            _elementoRepository = elementoRepository;
            _postoRepository = postoRepository;
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Elementos
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            //Inner Join C# vai buscar os dados da tabela posto e cruza com a do elemento
            var elemento = _context.Elementos.Include(p => p.posto);
            return View(elemento);
            //return View(_elementoRepository.GetAll());
        }

        // GET: Elementos/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var elemento = await _elementoRepository.GetByIdAsync(id.Value);

            if (elemento == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(elemento);
        }

        // GET: Elementos/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            var model = new AddElementoViewModel
            {
                Postos = _postoRepository.GetComboPostos()
            };
            return View(model);
        }

        // POST: Elementos/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(AddElementoViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                await _elementoRepository.AddElementoAsync(model);
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(model);
        }

        // GET: Elementos/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var elemento = await _elementoRepository.GetByIdAsync(id.Value);
            if (elemento == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(elemento);
        }

        // POST: Elementos/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Pnome,Mnome,Unome,Posto,Nbarra,Qhonra,Qreserva,Estado")] Elemento elemento)
        {
            if (id != elemento.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    await _elementoRepository.UpdateAsync(elemento);

                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!await _elementoRepository.ExistAsync(elemento.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(elemento);
        }

        // GET: Elementos/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var elemento = await _elementoRepository.GetByIdAsync(id.Value);

            if (elemento == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(elemento);
        }

        // POST: Elementos/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var elemento = await _elementoRepository.GetByIdAsync(id);
            await _elementoRepository.DeleteAsync(elemento);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }


    }
}
```

```
namespace FireHouseGest.web.Controllers
{
    public class EquipasController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IEquipaRepository _equipaRepository;
        //private readonly IElementoRepository _elementoRepository;
        private readonly DataContext _context;

        public EquipasController(IEquipaRepository equipaRepository, /*IElementoRepository elementoRepository,*/ DataContext context)
        {
            _equipaRepository = equipaRepository;
            //_elementoRepository = elementoRepository;
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Equipas
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            //var equipa = _context.Equipas.Include(e => e.GetElementos);
            return View(_equipaRepository.GetAll());
        }

        // GET: Equipas/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var equipa = await _equipaRepository.GetByIdAsync(id.Value);
            if (equipa == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(equipa);
        }

        // GET: Equipas/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Equipas/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Nome,Estado")] Equipa equipa)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                await _equipaRepository.CreateAsync(equipa);

                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(equipa);
        }

        // GET: Equipas/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var equipa = await _equipaRepository.GetByIdAsync(id.Value);
            if (equipa == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(equipa);
        }

        // POST: Equipas/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Nome,Estado")] Equipa equipa)
        {
            if (id != equipa.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    await _equipaRepository.UpdateAsync(equipa);
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!await _equipaRepository.ExistAsync(equipa.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(equipa);
        }

        // GET: Equipas/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var equipa = await _equipaRepository.GetByIdAsync(id.Value);
            if (equipa == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(equipa);
        }

        // POST: Equipas/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var equipa = await _equipaRepository.GetByIdAsync(id);
            await _equipaRepository.DeleteAsync(equipa);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        
    }
}
```

Repositories

````
namespace FireHouseGest.web.Data.Repository
{
    public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity
    {
        private readonly DataContext _context;
        public GenericRepository(DataContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
        {
            return _context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking();
        }

        public async Task<T> GetByIdAsync(int Id)
        {
            return await _context.Set<T>()
                .AsNoTracking()
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == Id);
        }

        public async Task CreateAsync(T entity)
        {
            await _context.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity);
            await SaveAllAsync();
        }

        public async Task DeleteAsync(T entity)
        {
            _context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
            await SaveAllAsync();
        }

        public async Task<bool> ExistAsync(int Id)
        {
            return await _context.Set<T>().AnyAsync(e => e.Id == Id);

        }
                  

        public async Task UpdateAsync(T entity)
        {
            _context.Set<T>().Update(entity);
            await SaveAllAsync();
        }
        public async Task<bool> SaveAllAsync()
        {
            return await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
        }
    }
}


```
   

```
namespace FireHouseGest.web.Data.Repository
{
    public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        IQueryable<T> GetAll();

        Task<T> GetByIdAsync(int Id);

        Task CreateAsync(T entity);

        Task UpdateAsync(T entity);

        Task DeleteAsync(T entity);

        Task<bool> ExistAsync(int Id);
    }
}


```
```
````

Comment: You only need to define a viewmodel that contains the data you want from the two tables, no need a third table.

Comment: I have done that. Was a little hard to understand at beginning but is working. Thx for the help